# Custom query parameter name in RAML

Tags: raml

I'm trying to use RAML to describe following API call

```
PUT /api/v1/kv_store?{key}={value}
```

It's a simple key-value storage. I need to specify that `key` value can be any string, and API console should give users possibility to enter it as well as any other parameter.

Is it doable at all? I'm reading RAML 1.0 spec and can't find a way to do it, so small example will be really great.

Comment: Not sure if it's feasible but if you would change your API to `?key={}&value={value}` it would then be easy to specify.

Comment: Sure, it's an solution, but changing API is pretty painful, and "make it easy describable by RAML" isn't a good enough reason, unfortunately

Comment: Gotcha, I wasn't sure if you had leeway to rethink your API or not.

Answer (score 0):

Your are doing it completely wrong.
please read [Documentation](https://github.com/raml-org/raml-spec/blob/master/versions/raml-10/raml-10.md/).

Correct way to implement `QueryParameters` by following code.
As this will cater your `http://api/v1/kv_store/`

```
/songs:
  put:
    queryParameters:
      id: number
      name: string
      type: string
      album: number
```

Comment: I've asked that question because I needed to do it that way. I needed a possibility to have variable parameter name, not fixed one.